# onUpdate and Transaction Document Lock

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a case where a user wants to register for a course.

If the course is full, a user is able to register on the waiting list. If a free slot opens for this course this user will be registered automatically. To implement the waiting list automation, I used a Cloud Function (CF) with a `.onUpdate` trigger, which works.

**CF Example:** The course is full. A participant unregisters. The CF fires and checks if there is a free slot in the course and if the user on the waiting list is not already registered. If so, then the CF registers the user from the waiting list in the course.

At the same time in the UI, when a slot becomes available I allow the same user that was already on the waiting list to register for the course. By registering for the course I remove him from the waiting list.

For this implementation, I used a `transaction` that completes only if the user is not already registered in the course.

For some reason sometimes the user gets registered twice.

**MY QUESTION IS:** Does the `onUpdate` function lock the document? Do I need a `transaction` within the `onUpdate` function to listen to the changes of the same document? => For me this would make no sense.

P.S. The easiest way to handle this bug is to make the user first unregister from the waiting list and then register for the course. Still, I want to understand how it could be possible to implement the above logic.

The in Flutter transaction:

```
@override
  Future<void> selfSetCourseParticipantWithStashedCreditPoint(
      String courseEventId, Participant participantToAdd) async {
    try {
      UsedCreditPointInfo participantsCreditPoint =
          participantToAdd.usedCreditPointInfo;
      await _firestore.runTransaction((transaction) async {
        // 1) Check if the customer does still have an available credit point left
        final userRef = _usersCollection.doc(participantToAdd.uid);
        var userDocumentSnapshot = await transaction.get(userRef);
        var stashedCreditPoints =
            userDocumentSnapshot.data()['${participantToAdd.creditPointPath}'];
        var creditPointExists = false;
        for (var usedCreditPointInfoMap in stashedCreditPoints) {
          var usedCreditPoint =
              UsedCreditPointInfo.fromMap(usedCreditPointInfoMap);
          if (usedCreditPoint == participantsCreditPoint) {
            creditPointExists = true;
            break;
          }
        }
        // if the credit point does not exist, then the transaction must fail
        if (!creditPointExists) return null;

        final courseRef = _courseEventsCollection.doc(courseEventId);
        final courseEventDocumentSnapshot = await transaction.get(courseRef);
        // 2) if the courseEvent document exists I have to check first if there are slots left
        var currentCourseEvent = CourseEvent.fromEntity(
            CourseEventEntity.fromSnapshot(courseEventDocumentSnapshot));
        //todo: add the remaining requirements, e.g., registration date limit
        if (currentCourseEvent.participants.length >=
            currentCourseEvent.maxParticipants) {
          return null;
        }

        if (currentCourseEvent.waitingList != null) {
          var waitingList = currentCourseEvent.waitingList;
          for (var i = 0; i < waitingList.length; i++) {
            final waitingListParticipant = waitingList[i];
            if (waitingListParticipant.uid == participantToAdd.uid) {
              waitingList.removeAt(i);
              break;
            }
          }
        }

        // add only if the participant is not already included to the list
        if (!currentCourseEvent.participants.contains(participantToAdd)) {
          currentCourseEvent = currentCourseEvent.copyWith(
            participants: List.from(currentCourseEvent.participants)
              ..add(participantToAdd),
          );

          // the user document exists at this point, thus update is sufficient
          transaction.update(
            userRef,
            {
              '${participantToAdd.creditPointPath}': FieldValue.arrayRemove(
                  [participantToAdd.usedCreditPointInfo?.toMap()])
            },
          );
          return transaction.set(
              courseRef, currentCourseEvent.toEntity().toMap());
        }
      });
    } catch (e, s) {
      return handleFirestoreError(e, s);
    }
  }
```

A snippet of my CF:

```
export const notifyOnCourseEventUpdateAndWaitingListRegistration = functions.firestore
  .document("CourseEvents/{courseEvent}")
  .onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
    return firestore
      .runTransaction(async (transaction) => {
        const courseEventRef = firestore
          .collection("CourseEvents")
          .doc(change.after.data().firebaseId);
        const courseEventSnapshot = await transaction.get(courseEventRef);
        const courseEvent = courseEventSnapshot.data() as CourseEvent;

        const currentCourseEvent =  change.after.data() as CourseEvent;
        const currentParticipants = currentCourseEvent.participants;
        const previousCourseEvent = change.before.data() as CourseEvent;
        const previousParticipants = previousCourseEvent.participants;
        const currentMaxParticipants = currentCourseEvent.maxParticipants;
        const currentWaitingList = currentCourseEvent.waitingList;
        ...
      })
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the onUpdate function lock the document?

No.

> Do I need a transaction within the onUpdate function to listen to the changes of the same document?

I'm not entirely sure what this question is asking, but in any case, if you want two bits of concurrently running code to be update to safely update the same document without overwriting each other, then you need a transaction.

Transactions do not "listen" to changes in documents.  They just ensure that two clients cannot overwrite each other when transacting on the same document by retrying the transaction handler function when a collision is detected.

Comment: Ah great. So this means that when the `.onUpdate()` triggers, the document can get still overwritten, e.g., from the client-side. If I implement a transaction within the `.onUpdate` and place the `change.before.data()` and `change.after.data()` within the transaction, will the data retrieved by these two functions, be the initial one no matter how often the transaction may retry?

Comment: Yes, that's true.  Triggers run some time after the document changed, and do not execute in any given order.  If you think the document might have changed again when the trigger executes, you should read the document again and process it.